# The store provider factory type Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory does not implement the IServiceProvider interface

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odp.net

I gave up with this problem. No web sites that tell about this problem is helping me.

First of all, I have Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 11.2.0.3.20, which is later than the version shown in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html

I am using VS2012 and in my computer, all works perfectly. The problem is when I publish the project and then copied to a Windows 2003 Server machine.

I chose that Oracle.DataAccess.dll will be copied to output directory and when I browse objects, I see that OracleClientFactory does implement IServiceProvider interface.

Since target machine has Windows Server 2003, I need to target .NET Framework 4.0.

I really dont't know what else to test. Can you help me?

Comment: Is it possible that that target machine is pulling the dll from its GAC?

Comment: Possibly, however, I have install the ODP version I used in development and the error was gone, but now, the entity framework cannot find the TNS even when tge tnsnamrs

Comment: ...... when the tnsnames.ora is present and configured.

Comment: Older versions of ODP.NET must update the machine config to avoid this error.Don't just copy files, run the installer.

Comment: I have used ODP.NET installer (the one I got from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html). I installed version 11.2.0.3.20. After that, the error disappeared, however, I have problems with this error now: "TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnection" even when the TNS is configured in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Finally I have used this page to solve the TNS problem: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_windows_tnsnames.ora_file_location.htm. For instance, I have added the TNS_ADMIN key in the Registry to point to the right tnsnames.ora folder. All works now.